# convert a string representation of a list of lists to a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, data-structures

how can I convert a string representation of a list of lists to a list data structure in python. For example if I have a string `k`:

```
k="['A',['B','C'],'D']"
```

The desired output I want is a list like below

```
 ['A',
['B','C'],
'D']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(k)
['A', ['B', 'C'], 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is a built-in python function that
parses the given string argument and evaluates it as an expression.

```py
>>> k = "['A',['B','C'],'D']"
>>> print(eval(k))
['A', ['B', 'C'], 'D']
```